# codeigniter add database ss

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a question about CodeIgniter
when I add a request for delivery and I filled the fields of the latter when adding, I put an attribute in the database named deliver that takes 0 by default which is automatically added, but since I can not add request

how do I add an application and to deliver value is automatically add the database with the value zero in each addition

Here is some code I'm using:

```
function add($name, $email, $phone, $depart, $arrivee, $capacite, $livrer, $uid)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('contacts', array(
        'name' => $name,
        'uid' => $uid
    ));
    if ($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    $this->db->insert('contacts', array(
        'name' => $name,
        'email' => $email,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'depart' => $depart,
        'arrivee' => $arrivee,
        'capacite' => $capacite,
        'livrer' => 0,
        'uid' => $uid
    ));
    $this->db->set('contacts', 'contacts+1', FALSE)->where('uid', $uid)->update('users');
    return TRUE;
}
```

}

```
public function add_contact()
{
    sleep(1);
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required|max_length[40]|callback_alpha_dash_space');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|max_length[40]|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Phone', 'required|max_length[8]|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('depart', 'Depart', 'required|max_length[15]|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('arrivee', 'Arrivee', 'required|max_length[15]|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('capacite', 'Capacite', 'required|max_length[15]|trim');


    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $message = "<strong>ajout</strong> echoué!";
        $this->json_response(FALSE, $message);
    } else {
        $is_added = $this->contact_model->add($this->input->post('name'), $this->input->post('email'), 
            $this->input->post('phone'),$this->input->post('depart'),$this->input->post('arrivee'),$this->input->post('capacite'), $this->session->userdata('uid'));

        if ($is_added) {
            $message = "<strong>".$this->input->post('name')."</strong> a été ajouté!";
            $this->json_response(TRUE, $message);
        } else {
            $message = "<strong>".$this->input->post('name')."</strong> existe deja!";
            $this->json_response(FALSE, $message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wut. I don't even know what you're asking here

Comment: 1 cid int(11)
3 name varchar(50)
4 email varchar(50)
5 phone int(8)
6 depart varchar(18)
7 arrivee varchar(18)
8 capacite int(15)
10 livrer tinyint(1)
this is my data base i would like to add all this data with a form and the last livrer will add automatically in the base with 0 
livrer mean deliver
i have test to add with many time but no chance

Comment: You're not making any sense at all. Without seeing your code or clearly wording your question, we're not going to be able to help you.

Comment: public function add($name, $email, $phone, $depart, $arrivee, $capacite,$livrer ,$uid)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('contacts', array('name' => $name, 'uid' => $uid));

        if ($query->num_rows == 1) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $this->db->insert('contacts', array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email, 'phone' => $phone,'depart' => $depart,'arrivee' => $arrivee,'capacite' => $capacite,'livrer' => 0 ,'uid' => $uid));
        $this->db->set('contacts', 'contacts+1', FALSE)
            ->where('uid', $uid)
            ->update('users');
        return TRUE;
    }

Comment: It looks like your code already sets `livrer` to be 0 with any insert.

Comment: yes but when i click add boutton nothing is added also the deliver is no added in the database

Comment: See my answer re: investigating the return value.

Comment: Please put your question in french by comment i will translate it to the other folks be able to help you. (Ecrit ta question en français en commentaire stp)

Comment: merci :) je veut ajouter une livraison avec ses donées et je veut dans chaque ajout une variable livrer de valeur 0 celle ci signifie que la livraison n'a pas été livrer .

avant d'ajouter livrer a ma base tout ce passe bien mais depuis que j'ai ajouter livrer a la base meme pas il ajoute une livraison dans la base 

donc je veut a chaque demande ajouté automatiquement la variable 0 a ma base avec la demande 

merci pour votre patience.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your `add` method is returning true or false. It looks like it won't continue if the contact doesn't already exist.

From your controller:

```
if($this->your_model->add([...]) == TRUE) {
 echo 'This user was added';
}
else {
 echo 'The user didn\'t exist.';
}
```

Failing that check if your code is indeed connecting to your database and that the table structure is valid.

Comment: i add the function of my controller my problem is if i delete the livrer the function add the request in the database but with liver is not added anythink